# Function to take the size of a list and retrieve how many tables it will occupy if the size of the table is 13 entries

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically, I want a function in Google Sheets Scripts that takes the size of a list of itens and take the number of pages it will occupy (my table only contains 13 rows at once).
Example, if my list has 30 items, I want that function to retrieve the number 3 (13+13+4 = 3 pages). For now I tried this, it doesnt work.

I hope it was easy to understand and thank you in advance.

```
  var nr_pag = 0;
  var nr_pag_source = search_sheet.getRange("K33:L33");
  
  while (pages_aux > -13) {
    nr_pag++;
    pages_aux-13;
  }
  nr_pag_source.setValue("pág.: 1 de "+nr_pag);
```

Answer (score 1):

Already got it.

```
  var nr_pag = 0;
  var nr_pag_source = search_sheet.getRange("K33:L33");
  nr_pag = Math.ceil(paginas_aux/13);
  nr_pag_source.setValue("pág.: 1 de "+nr_pag);
```